# Using COM object in C#

Tags: c#, dll, com

I'm trying to use TrustCommerce in my website. I installed dll files from the website, but I can't use it' I'm supposed to be able to use `myObject.PushParam(string)` and it's not working. Is there something I'm missing here? I found an [article](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/web/soa/Implement-credit-card-processing-with-TrustCommerce/0,339024632,320276100,00.htm) about it in PHP:

```
     public static void TrustCommerce()
     {
         //TCLinkNET.TClinkClass.
         object myObject = Orders.COMCreateObject("TCLINKCOMLib.TClinkClass");
     }

     public static object COMCreateObject(string sProgID)
     {
         // We get the type using just the ProgID
         Type oType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(sProgID);

         if (oType != null)
         {
             return Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
         }

         return null;
     }
```

Comment: is the site in medium trust ?

Comment: it's not working cause i'm supposed to be able to use it's functions like PushParam and it give me an error :(( just click on the link above and you will be able to know what i'm talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

add COM reference to your project, then an introp assembly will be generated for the COM. the way you are using requires reflection to invoke COM methods. 3.5 or less, do not forget to distribute the interop assembly with your application installer.

Comment: i did it i guess we can use it in c# as  TCLinkNET.TClinkClass tclink = new TCLinkNET.TClinkClass(); thank you all